# how to integrate an MTN Momoapi for money collection and disbursement into your django application?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

i want itegrate mtn momoapi into my django project so that i can be able to capture the details of apyments in the database

i already managed to signup to mtn sandbox, and writen codes but not the one integration of mtn into the system

Comment: Could you provide more clarity? Not many users here know about mtn (I do btw). Also show what you've tried. Your question needs details

Comment: this is the link to my project https://dru-interiors.onrender.com/